# CSS Put arrows on each side of a Box(div)

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Need help on how to put an arrow on each side of a box pointing outward.

I have the box and the basic CSS for an arrow I saw on another stack question.

Need help creating four arrows in that box

Im a java developer so this is not my cup of tea

Box:

```css
#myBox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
/*Chevron*/
.Chevron {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  /*height should be double border*/
}
.Chevron:before,
.Chevron:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  border: 25px solid transparent;
  /*adjust size*/
}
/*Change four 'top' values below to rotate (top/right/bottom/left)*/

.Chevron:before {
  top: 0;
  border-top-color: #b00;
  /*Chevron Color*/
}
.Chevron:after {
  top: -50px;
  /*adjust thickness*/
  border-top-color: #fff;
  /*Match background colour*/
}
```

```html
<div id="myBox"></div>





<i class="Chevron"></i>
```

Comment: Any image of how exactly the two arrows should be? Should they look like speech bubble arrows on either or side (or) should the shape with arrows look like a hexagon?

Comment: at the top-middle of the box should be an arrow pointing up....right middle should be an arrow pointing right..etc

Comment: all four side....tip of arrows should be touching its corresponding side of the box

Comment: is the box always going to be square?

Comment: yes the box will be that static size square

Comment: @DocHoliday: Sorry how wide should the longer side (hypotenuse) of the triangle be? Is it same length as the sides of the square? It would still be good if you could show an image just so that nobody takes the effort to post an answer and then finds it to be wide off the mark.

Comment: @Harry If you look at the snippet of the arrow.  Its the exact size I need relative to the box size.  Just create four of those parallel to each other inside of the box all pointing outward to the side they are looking at

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/v8fs0oLr/ or http://jsfiddle.net/v8fs0oLr/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking to interact with these shapes, you'd be better to go with a different approach to making your triangles, rather than a border hack.

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.touch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 200%;
  width: 200%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrap:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  top: 25%;
  left: 100%;
}
.wrap:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  top: 100%;
  left: 75%;
}
.wrap:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  top: 75%;
  left: 0;
}
.touch:hover {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span class="wrap"><span class="touch"></span></span>
  <span class="wrap"><span class="touch"></span></span>
  <span class="wrap"><span class="touch"></span></span>
  <span class="wrap"><span class="touch"></span></span>

</div>
```

i have used the `nth-child` in order to position the arrows correctly. I have also needed to used a wrapper div [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24808936/3436942) as the border-hack won't work on a hit-test.

Comment: This is what Im looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

Use Css [triangle](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/). Do you need something like this?

[image]

For each side, use the code below to make a triangle:

```
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 100px 100px 100px 0;
border-color: transparent #007bff transparent transparent;
```

Here is a [working demo](http://jsbin.com/duguqoxapo/1/edit?html,css,output).

Comment: haha.  this is what I need.  I just need the arrows INSIDE the box and smaller with the tips of the arrow touching the sides

Comment: So, move and update the posiition and the width of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to do this with 3 elements using CSS transforms and positioning. Is that what you were trying to achieve?

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.container .triangles {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: yellow;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}

.container .triangles .box {
  width: 50px; 
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangles">
    <div class="box">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution, but i don't think it is fully cross browser - i mean past versions of IE.